# What is the file-format of an email message that is stored in on Apache server?

Tags: email, apache-http-server, file-format

I have made a backup of my Windows LiveMail messages directly from the server (Apache / Linux).
The files have strange long names and I can open them in a text editor although the result is not very readable and I am not able to view the attachments.

This is an example of the filename:
1439205208.H158450P21923.my.hosting.provider.com,S=1752243_2,S

In the header, I see that the Content-Type is: multipart/alternative

Apparently, the files are in a format that is at least unknown to me and I cannot find a program on my PC that is able to open the files in a readable manner.

My question is: with what software could I display an email message including its attachment?

Answer (score 2):

The format you are seeing is [Maildir](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailboxFormat/Maildir). That's a format that is not directly readable by MUA (Mail User Agents), i.e., Thunderbird, Outlook, etc., even those files are plain files containing the mail data.

You need a software that can handle those files and retrieve it to a MUA (client), for example via IMAP. Examples of software (MTA, Mail Transport Agents) that can handle those files are and later retrieve them to a MUA: [Dovecot](https://www.dovecot.org/), [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), [Exim](http://www.exim.org/)...

This filename format, although it may look senseless, has some meaning. You can check for details [here](http://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html).

Comment: Thanks nKn for this clear answer. As I understand, I need two different software programmes. First I need to use some MTA and after that I can read the file in a MUA.

Comment: EDIT: I tried to install the MTA software you suggested. I suppose I first need to create some sort of a mail server environment on my local computer, isn't it? Is there no way to view a message in an easier way? Would it be an idea to copy the backed up message to a cur directory and try to view it with a webmail client on the server?

Comment: EDIT: Thanks again @nKn since your answer really got me on track. I have found te Bitrecover Maildir Reader at [http://www.bitrecover.com/](http://www.bitrecover.com/). The whole original message shows up, including attachments and images.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use it the intended way (which should be most of the times). You can find tools that will open those files as well, but this should just be for punctual use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again @nKn since your answer really got me on track. I have found a programme that is able to read the files in maildir format that are in my email backup.

It's called Bitrecover Maildir Reader and you can find it at http://www.bitrecover.com

The whole message is displayed, including attachments and images.

Comment: @Seth The first answer I have credited as a useful answer. The second answer is my own answer and I have put it there as a resume of the answer I received from nKn plus the method I have found to open the maildir files.